# PHP 7 MongoDB - drop all databases

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to unit test my mongodb methods, thus I need a tearDown() method to flush my entire mongo database after testing.

Here is the function:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    $databases = $this->mongoClient->listDatabases();
    foreach ($databases as $db) {
        $db.dropDatabase();
    }
}
```

However it can't see the method on my $db.

```
Error: Call to undefined function Api\Test\Unit\dropDatabase()
```

It seems listDatabases() only return some information model of my dbs, not the actual databases themselves:

```
/var/www/html/tests/backend/Service/MongoStorageTest.php:35:
class MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfo#1563 (3) {
  public $name =>
  string(5) "local"
  public $sizeOnDisk =>
  double(83886080)
  public $empty =>
  bool(false)
}

/var/www/html/tests/backend/Service/MongoStorageTest.php:35:
class MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfo#1483 (3) {
  public $name =>
  string(2) "db"
  public $sizeOnDisk =>
  double(83886080)
  public $empty =>
  bool(false)
}
```

Is there any practical or simple way to really select them, or just drop everything with one method?

Comment: `$db.dropDatabase();` - PHP does NOT use . to access methods, this is valid: `$db->dropDatabase();` given dropDatabase method does exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [method to drop](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBClient-dropDatabase/) is actually on `MongoClient`, and of course there is [`getName()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBModelDatabaseInfo-getName/) from the `MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfo` types that are returned from [`listDatabases()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBClient-listDatabases/)

```
public function tearDown()
{
    $databases = $this->mongoClient->listDatabases();
    foreach ($databases as $db) {
        $this->mongoClient->dropDatabase($db->getName());
    }
}
```

Alternately you could [`selectDatabase()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBClient-selectDatabase/) and use the [`drop()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBDatabase-drop/) method on MongoDB\Database:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    $databases = $this->mongoClient->listDatabases();
    foreach ($databases as $db) {
        $this->mongoClient->selectDatabase($db->getName())->drop();
    }
}
```

But to my mind that's a little more terse, and the first form feels more expressive.

Being that a "database" is a base container for namespace, then there actually is no command to "drop everything". Listing and looping the list is how you do it. Bottom line is if it's not in the ["command reference"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/), then there is no such thing.

Comment: I'm not using MongoClient, the PHP manual says it is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php). I am in the MongoDB/Client library.

Comment: @MattSom The documentation links from the answer a the PHPLIB driver. Clearly shown when you actually look at them. Not the driver you are pointing to. Read the documentation in the links.

Comment: I admit I've lost you there, I only meant the MongoClient solution is not good for me. Still, the getName() logic is what I was looking. Thank you.